# Formatting pagination

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a pagination at the bottom of a WordPress results set using the code;

```
function realestatepro_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2)
{
    $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;

    global $paged;
    if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

    if($pages == '')
    {
        global $wp_query;
        $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        if(!$pages)
        {
            $pages = 1;
        }
    }

    if(1 != $pages)
    {
        echo "<ul class='paginate-links'>";
//        if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
        if($paged != 1) echo "<li><a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged-1)."'>Previous</a></li>";
        for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
        {
            if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
            {
                echo ($paged == $i)? "<li class='active' ><a href='".$i."' >".$i."</a></li>":"<li><a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' >".$i."</a></li>";
            }
        }
        if($paged != $pages) echo "<li><a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged+1)."'>Next</a></li>";
//        if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a>";
        echo "</ul>\n";
    }
}
```

and I am using the following CSS to style the numbering

```css
.paginate-links li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 margin: 0 2px 0 0;
 border: 1px solid #e0e0de;
 line-height: 1;
 text-decoration: none!important;
}

.paginate-links li.active a {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 color: #ffffff;
 background: #3399FF;
}

.paginate-links li.active a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <hr>
    <ul class='paginate-links'>
        <li class='active' ><a href='1' >1</a></li>
        <li><a href='LINK TO PAGE 2>2</a></li>
        <li><a href='LINK TO NEXT PAGE>Next</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The background for the active page however, only affect the area behind the number and not the whole box. I have tried using absolute pixel heights and widths to no avail. I also can't seem to remove the text underline when a page number is hovered. I can't see where I am going wrong.

Comment: @Thaillie I have now added the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed a view things.

I've moved the padding style from only the active link to all links and added `display: block;` to hyperlinks.

As for removing the `text-decoration` when you have it on an anchor tag i.e.

```
.paginate-links li.active a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

You actually have to hover over the anchor element, whose width was less than the list item

A solution to this is adding the hover style over the list item:

```
.paginate-links li:hover a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

However this will remove the underline for each of the pagination items (including non-active. If you just want the active item to have its `text-decoration` removed then this will work:

```
.paginate-links li.active:hover a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**Full Example**

```css
.paginate-links li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0de;
  line-height: 1;
  text-decoration: none!important;
}
.paginate-links li a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
}
.paginate-links li.active a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #3399FF;
}
.paginate-links li:hover a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
  <hr>
  <ul class='paginate-links'>
    <li class='active'><a href='1'>1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='LINK TO PAGE 2'>2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='LINK TO NEXT PAGE'>Next</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```